# IE7 nested div display bug

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-7

I have 2 alert boxes inside of a "shadow" layer I use to cover the rest of the page.  When a user clicks a button, I show the shadow layer and the appropriate alert box.  when they finish, I hide both those divs.  This works great in all browsers except IE7, where if you open one alert box, close it, then open the other, both alert boxes show.  How can I get around this issue?

```
<div id="shadowLayer" style="display:none; z-index:2001; position:fixed; width:100%; height:100%;>
<div id="MessageLightbox" style="display:none; z-index:3001; position:absolute;>  
<iframe></iframe>
</div>
<div id="RecordLightbox" style="display:none; z-index:4001; position:absolute;>
<iframe></iframe>
</div>
</div>

$('#shadowLayer').css('display', 'block');
$('#RecordLightbox').css('display', 'block');

$('#shadowLayer').css('display', 'none');
$('#RecordLightbox').css('display', 'none');

$('#shadowLayer').css('display', 'block');
$('#MessageLightbox').css('display', 'block');

$('#shadowLayer').css('display', 'none');
$('#MessageLightbox').css('display', 'none');
```

Answer (score 1):

Its a bug in IE.  Try some recomendation off of google for work arounds with nested div's.

Try the link "The IE 'non-disappearing content' bug"

from

http://www.positioniseverything.net/explorer.html

Comment: Thanks for the link.  Their solutions didn't work, so I just ended up giving the boxes separate shadow layers.